# Android SDK Eclipse Error

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I'm trying to get some of the samples to run from the Android SDK samples but am having troubles getting them to run on my device.

I am running windows 7 64-bit and my device is an LG Optimus Slider.

I installed the SDK through eclipse indigo (the SDK is the 2.1 version).

I am able to successfully run the samples on an Android Virtual Device but when I try on my LG Optimus SLider I get the following:

```
[2012-01-02 16:39:57 - ApiDemos] ------------------------------
[2012-01-02 16:39:57 - ApiDemos] Android Launch!
[2012-01-02 16:39:57 - ApiDemos] adb is running normally.
[2012-01-02 16:39:57 - ApiDemos] Performing com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos activity launch
[2012-01-02 16:39:57 - ApiDemos] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please      select a target device.
[2012-01-02 16:40:03 - ApiDemos] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2012-01-02 16:40:03 - ApiDemos] WARNING: Unknown device API version!
[2012-01-02 16:40:03 - ApiDemos] Uploading ApiDemos.apk onto device 'A10000199B0EF7'
[2012-01-02 16:40:04 - ApiDemos] Installing ApiDemos.apk...
[2012-01-02 16:40:04 - ApiDemos] Failed to install ApiDemos.apk on device 'A10000199B0EF7!
[2012-01-02 16:40:04 - ApiDemos] closed
[2012-01-02 16:40:04 - ApiDemos] Failed to install ApiDemos.apk on device 'A10000199B0EF7': closed
[2012-01-02 16:40:04 - ApiDemos] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: closed
[2012-01-02 16:40:04 - ApiDemos] Launch canceled!
```

Also might be related, when the device chooser comes up in eclipse the target on my device is listed as unknown.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope at least one of the following will help:

1. You have to uninstall the application from the application manager
   on your cellphone before you can install it again.
2. Also check the version compatibilty issue
3. Apparently, your device is not properl connected

Comment: It never installed to my device so unfortunately number 1 can't help me.  And i think my device is properly connected, it shows up in device manager as Android Sooner Single ADB Interface and debugging is on.

Comment: @JeffK try the others. For 2, what is your OS and what API level are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. The OS on the device is Android 2.3.4 and I'm using API level 2.1

Comment: @JeffK check if debugging is enabled on your CellPhone and verify you have the correct USB link type to your PC.